# Trying to copy a set of specific strings from many text files in a directory and paste them in a new text file

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and I am trying to sort through a directory's files that start with 'O0' and copy any string in the text files that has an 'F', 'T', or 'S' in them, and paste, preferably just that string, (but the whole line would still work) in a new text file, preferably on the desktop. It is making the text file, but it is blank, and python does not close the file. Here's what I have so far:

```
import os

 # definitions
 directory = (r'\directoryname')
 feedsspeeds = open('feedsspeeds.txt', 'a+')


 # scanning through sub folders
 for file in os.scandir(directory):
    if file.path.startswith("O0"):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
                for line in file:
                    if ('F', 'T', 'S') in line:
                            feedsspeeds.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `for line in file:`. You want to loop on `f`, not `file`.

As a side note I can foresee a problem with `if ('F', 'T', 'S') in line:`. The `in` operator on a string requires a string as left operand. You are providing a tuple.

What you want to do is `if 'F' in line or 'T' in line or 'S' in line:`.

##### Bonus : filtering to output only relevants parts

Warning : untested code

```
for file in os.scandir(directory):
    if file.path.startswith("O0"):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    for item in line.split(): # by default split() use space as separator
                        if 'F' in item or 'T' in item or 'S' in item:
                            feedsspeeds.append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you this finally gave me an output. As a side question is there a way I can only output the string with F, T, or S instead of the whole line?

Comment: Glad it helped. Filtering the content of the line would require some samples or at least a description of a line.

Comment: For example: instead of outputting the line `S2200 M03` It would only output `S2200`. Another example line being `G01 X1.826 F4.` Where I only want the 'F4' to be outputted.

Comment: Edited to answer the bonus question. Are those some GCODE files ? And by the way if you can mark my answer as correct, thx :)

Comment: Yes they are! I am a CNC programmer. Thanks for the help, marked as correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place you are probably getting an `AttributeError` error that `append` is not known. Because you try to append your text to the TextIOwrapper (`feeds speeds`). You have to use the `write` method to append the text to the file content.

Also note that your file is read and written from the current directory, so `./feedsspeeds.txt`. As long as you are not executing this script from you Desktop folder, the file will also not be written there.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors but I went ahead and changed the append to write and it still is a blank text file. I'm not too concerned about where the new document is placed as I just need to use it once. Just trying to get it to work.

Comment: So the line `feedsspeeds.append(line)` is never executed. This means there is something wrong with your `if` and `for` loops so it is not reached.

Comment: I see, and I'm sure there is something wrong but with no errors and minimal experience I can't seem to figure out what could be wrong with them.